# Отображение данных из JSON в ListView(курс валют) - Android

Tags: java, android, json, adapter

Почему-то не отображаются актуальные данные из JSON файла которые тяну с сайта RBC. Создал класс в MainActivity:

```
 private class GetRbcExchangeRates extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    public ArrayList<CurrencyRateModel> listOfCurrency = new ArrayList<>();
    private final String httpAddress = "https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        StringBuilder jSonResult = new StringBuilder();

        //listOfCurrency = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(httpAddress);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                jSonResult.append(line);

            }


        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            publishProgress("MESSAGE", "Отсутствует подключение к интернет!");
        }
        finally {

            if(connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();

            try {
                if(bufferedReader !=null)
                    bufferedReader.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        try {

            JSONObject rbcGETRates = new JSONObject(jSonResult.toString());
            JSONObject jSonValute = rbcGETRates.getJSONObject("Valute");
            Iterator<String> arrayKey = jSonValute.keys();

            while(arrayKey.hasNext()) {

                String key = arrayKey.next();
                JSONObject jSonItem = jSonValute.getJSONObject(key);
                CurrencyRateModel currencyitems = new CurrencyRateModel();
                currencyitems.id = jSonItem.getString("ID");
                currencyitems.nameCode = jSonItem.getString("NumCode");
                currencyitems.charCode = jSonItem.getString("CharCode");
                currencyitems.nominal = jSonItem.getInt("Nominal");
                currencyitems.name = jSonItem.getString("Name");
                currencyitems.value = jSonItem.getDouble("Value");
                currencyitems.previous = jSonItem.getDouble("Previous");
                listOfCurrency.add(currencyitems);
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        ListView lsView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.currencyView);
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, listOfCurrency);
        lsView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        if(values[0].equals("MESSAGE")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, values[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

Класс - Модель с полями:

```
public class CurrencyRateModel {

public String id;
public String nameCode;
public String charCode;
public int nominal;
public String name;
double value;
double previous;
```

}

И адаптер:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context ctx;
private ArrayList<CurrencyRateModel> arrayList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public MyAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<CurrencyRateModel> arrayList) {

    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    inflater = ((Activity)ctx).getLayoutInflater();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    ViewHolder vh;

    if(convertView == null) {

        vh = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemcurrency, null);
        vh.tvTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        vh.tvDescription = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        convertView.setTag(vh);

    }
    else {

        vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        vh.tvTitle.setText("1");
        vh.tvDescription.setText("2");
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    TextView tvTitle, tvDescription;
}
```

}

В методе onCreate делаю так:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // async TASK Run
    GetRbcExchangeRates async = new GetRbcExchangeRates();
    async.execute();
}
```

Так же создан отдельный ресурс файл c 2 TextView:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#555"/>
```

Отладку произвожу на планшете с Lollipop 5.1. При запуске пустота, если свернешь приложение, а после снова разворачиваешь, в ListView записываются цифры 1 и 2 (что в адаптере в блоке else); При отладке видно, что в структуру данных записываются валидные распарсенные данные из сайта, какая то проблема в отображении данных. Я вывел в лог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так. Буду благодарен за любую помощь, так как всего пару недель щупаю эту платформу.

Comment: Перенесите код из `onPreExecute` в `onPostExecute` и добавьте четвертую строку: `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, теперь такая проблема, при запуске приложения выводятся данные в ListView из блока else метода @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent). Если убрать проверку и закоментировать блок else, то выводится пустой ListView.

Comment: что, вы ожидаете, должно появится, кроме 1 и 2, если вы сами явно указали выводить эти числа?

Comment: Почему явно? Это я для проверки, по идее так: если View (та что convertView) пустой, то я тяну из Json, иначе цифры 1,2 просто для отладки, посмотреть что в ListView. Так вот, я уже писал, что я убираю блок else и оставляю только: `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemcurrency, null);
        vh.tvTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        vh.tvDescription = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        convertView.setTag(vh);`

Comment: в списке появляется то, что вы устанавливаете сеттером для виджетов (методом `setText()`), в первом блоке не происходит ничего, кроме кэширования, никакие данные там не выводятся и не присутствуют даже, почему вы считаете, что что то тяните из JSON?

Comment: хорошим решением ваших затруднений будет почитать хорошую [книгу по андроид-разработке](https://m.habrahabr.ru/company/piter/blog/335146/), а не использовать низкопродуктивный метод тыка. В книге по ссылке есть **все** для того, чтобы писать качественные приложения и они будут работать

Comment: в андроид по умолчанию нет биндинга данных на виджеты, как в С#, все нужно указывать явно в коде, в какой виджет какие данные должны быть помещены. Есть библиотека Data Binding, которую нужно подключать, чтобы был биндинг

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код по обработке данных (вывод на экран), полученных в асинхронном потоке, должен выполнятся в методе `onPostExecute()` - выполнить **после** завршения потока, то есть, когда данные сформированы.

В адаптере вместо

```
vh.tvTitle.setText("1");
```

логично предположить, что нужно выводить данные для этой позиции, а не хардкорный текст - 1.

```
 vh.tvTitle.setText(arrayList.get(position).name);
```

целиком метод `getView()`(не знаю, что нужно выводить в description, пусть будет значение `value`) + комментарии, что именно там происходит и исправленное условие (закрывающая скобка не в том месте была):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder vh;

    if(convertView == null) {
        // создаем объект-холдер для кэширования ссылок на виджеты
        vh = new ViewHolder();
        // получаем объект айтема списка, который парсим из xml-разметки
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemcurrency, null);
        // получаем ссылки на виджеты в айтеме
        vh.tvTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        vh.tvDescription = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        // сохраняем холдер для переиспользования
        convertView.setTag(vh);

    }
    else {
        // получаем холдер с кэшированными ссылками на виджеты
        vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // в виджеты айтема выводим данные согласно текущей позиции в списке
    vh.tvTitle.setText(arrayList.get(position).name);
    vh.tvDescription.setText(Double.toString(arrayList.get(position).value));

    return convertView;
}
```

Числовой тип должен быть преобразован в `String` перед передачей в метод `setText()`.

Подробнее о [устройстве адаптера с холдером](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/listview/listview-perfomance.php)

Метод `getItem()` не должен возвращать null, он должен возвращать содержимое айтема (данные для него):

```
@Override
public CurrencyRateModel getItem(int position) {
   return arrayList.get(position);
}
```

Так же в модели данных стоит подумать о геттерах/сеттерах, в Java это считается хорошим тоном.

Comment: Спасибо, по поводу property вы правильно заметили. Я просто долго кодил на C# и там гетеры и сеттеры очень удобные. В Java я пока с ними не разбирался и быстро в модели применил поля - исправлюсь, как только увижу данные в ListView. Оставил только передачу контекста во View - ` vh = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemcurrency, null);
        vh.tvTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        vh.tvDescription = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        convertView.setTag(vh);` И пусто....

Comment: у вас там еще скобка одна не там в условии

Comment: чтобы данные появились в списке - их нужно туда поместить, (явно указать, какие именно данные в какой именно виджет нужно выводить) вы же ничего для этого не делаете и почему то считаете, что они сами как то поместятся куда надо,  но в андроид по дефолту нет биндинга, как в С#.

Comment: Спасибо! Все заработало. Буду теперь рефакторить!